# Why does this expression evaluate to 0?

Tags: matlab, logic, boolean-logic

Why does the expression:

```
-5 < -3 < -1
```

evaluate to 0 in MATLAB? The separate statements each evaluate to true, so I'm confused as to why it's evaluating to false.

Comment: you would need to break that into two comparisons if you intended to do a comparison of -3 to the other values (as in an inequality). Something like this  `(-5 < -3) && (-3 < -1)`

Answer (score 14):

Because it really looks like this:

```
(-5 < -3) < -1
```

-5 < -3 is true, which is also 1.

1 < -1 is false, which is also 0.

Final answer: 0.

Answer (score 11):

[MATLAB operates left to right for the less than operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html).

So you are evaluating

```
-5 < -3 < -1
TRUE < -1
FALSE
```

Comment: Ouch... ~30 seconds kills you lol. Have a vote from me anyway.

Comment: Haha. I was just about to delete my answer

Comment: Nah leave it.  This answer is good because you have linked to official documentation regarding the behaviour.  The answer with the highest votes does this out of pure logic, but you've provided an official link of where this behaviour is documented in addition to explaining how the result is produced.  I'd personally accept this answer if I was the OP.

Comment: Psh, I don't care either way.  I don't know the internals of MATLAB *at all* but boolean logic?  That I know well.  Most languages will have syntax errors with the `-5 < -3 < -1` statement because they care that booleans can't be compared with integers, but in less strict languages a boolean TRUE *is exactly the same as* an integer 1 (any non-zero value evaluates *to* true, but true is explicitly stored as 1).  So I immediately understood what was going on.  The parens are also something that's always there.  Even `5 + 3 + 2` is really `(5 + 3) + 2` but we don't write them down.

Comment: @Draco18s Actually, in Python, doing `-5 < -3 < -1` is equivalent to doing `-5 < -3 && -3 < -1`, which will evaluate to `True` [link - start at *Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily*...](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).  We can't assume that this assumed behaviour is the same amongst all programming languages.  That's why I prefer this answer as it linked to official documentation.  FWIW, I did upvote your answer as it got to the point quickly but you can't assume from logic that your answer holds True for all programming languages.

Comment: @Draco18s true, but some old notable languages are even worse. The fact is that in C, it is not defined whether `-5 < -3` or `-3 < -1` is evaluated first... Tough luck or something I guess. I would say it is good practice to have parathesis where they belong in case of operators with the same priority.

Comment: @patrik That is not true, comparison operators have left-to-right associativity in C. See for example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order and https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes you are right. This was written at an age where I was younger and dumber.